# Manipulando dados relacionados Asp.net e C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação ASP.NET, que tem como objetivo cadastrar eventos e adicionar clientes a esses eventos cadastrados, formando uma lista de clientes para cada evento.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:
Na tabela Eventos existe três tipos de entrada (tipo inteiro - porque guarda a quantidade de entrada disponível para tal evento), que são Cortesia, Bônus e Vip. Até aí tudo bem. Quando vou adicionar um novo cliente para um determinado evento, preciso selecionar o tipo de entrada dele em um radio button(Cortesia, Bônus e Vip). Sempre que eu adicionar um cliente, preciso que a quantidade do tipo de entrada de Eventos diminua 1.
O que eu não estou conseguindo é recuperar o valor do tipo de entrada selecionado no radiobutton para fazer a manipulação dos dados.

OBS: No formulário para incluir cliente eu seleciono em um dropdownlist o evento desejado. Não sei se precisam dessa informação ou se por meio disso consigo recuperar os valores de cada tipo de entrada.

Parece ser simples, mas como estou no início, travei neste ponto.

```
protected void btnIncluir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var db = new TheOneWebEntities();
    var cliente = new Cliente();
    cliente.Nome = tbNome.Text;
    cliente.Cpf = tbCpf.Text;
    cliente.Email = tbEmail.Text;
    cliente.Telefone = tbTelefone.Text;
    cliente.EventoId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlEvento.SelectedValue);

    int totalEntrada;

    if (rbCortesia.Checked)
    {
        if (evento.Cortesia <= 0)
        {
            Util.Alertar("Cortesia esgotada");
        }
        else
        {
            totalEntrada = cliente.Evento.Cortesia - 1;
            cliente.Evento.Cortesia = totalEntrada;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (rbBonus.Checked)
        {
            if (evento.Bonus <= 0)
            {
                Util.Alertar("Bônus esgotado");
            }
            else
            {
                totalEntrada = cliente.Evento.Bonus - 1;
                cliente.Evento.Bonus = totalEntrada;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (rbVip.Checked)
            {
                if (evento.Vip <= 0)
                {
                    Util.Alertar("VIP esgotado");
                }
                else
                {
                    totalEntrada = cliente.Evento.Vip - 1;
                    cliente.Evento.Vip = totalEntrada;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    var dataCadastro = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    cliente.DataCadastro = Convert.ToDateTime(dataCadastro);
    cliente.UsuarioId = WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

    db.Clientes.Add(cliente);
    db.SaveChanges();
    Util.Alertar("Cliente adicionado com sucesso!");
    Response.Redirect("~/User/MeusClientes.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Apenas complementando a resposta do Cigano

crie o RadioButtonList dessa forma:

```
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdgTipoEntrada" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="Cortesia">Cortesia</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Bonus">Bônus</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="VIP">Vip</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

CodeBehind

```
switch (rdgTipoEntrada.SelectedValue)
        {
            case "Cortesia":

                if (evento.Cortesia <= 0)
                {
                    Util.Alertar("Cortesia esgotada");
                }
                else
                {
                    totalEntrada = cliente.Evento.Cortesia - 1;
                    cliente.Evento.Cortesia = totalEntrada;
                }

                break;
            case "Bonus":

                if (evento.Bonus <= 0)
                {
                    Util.Alertar("Bônus esgotado");
                }
                else
                {
                    totalEntrada = cliente.Evento.Bonus - 1;
                    cliente.Evento.Bonus = totalEntrada;
                }

                break;
            case "VIP":

                if (rbVip.Checked)
                {
                    if (evento.Vip <= 0)
                    {
                        Util.Alertar("VIP esgotado");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        totalEntrada = cliente.Evento.Vip - 1;
                        cliente.Evento.Vip = totalEntrada;
                    }
                }


                break;

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Se for uma `RadioButtonList`, acho que fica mais fácil conferir o valor pela própria `RadioButtonList`:

```
switch (rdgTipoEntrada.SelectedItem.Value.ToString())
{
    case "Cortesia":
       ...
    case "Bônus":
       ...
    case "VIP":
       ...
}
```